# Support XML parsing in Paw

Tags: paw-app

Is XML type response parsing on the plans for PAW anytime soon? I know we can parse JSON body and create Dynamic values from them. I would love to have that feature enabled for XML response bodies too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse and create dynamic values from XML, see:

[image: Parse XML with Response Dynamic Value in Paw]

To manually add a "response parsed dynamic value":

[image]

But there is no way to display the actual XML tree in a pretty way like Paw has for JSON.